# Can i have labels for the if in django template tags?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using a lot of django if blocks in my templates and some of them are nested too. Is it possible to give a lable to these if blocks as if we have labels for blocks. for example,

```
{% block "label_name" %}
{% endblock "label_name" %}
```

This makes me easily follow the start and end of the block. Is there something like this,

```
{% "label_name " if student %}
{% endif "label_name"%}
```

Comment: Maybe you're doing it wrong and writing too much logic in templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using the built-in comment syntax to keep track? Ideally, if it's too hard to keep track of your if-blocks, you should refactor the template code into multiple files, including large chunks within an if-block, so you can read them much more easily.

The comment syntax you'd find most useful is the short-hand one, ala:

```
{% if student %}
{% endif %} {# / student #}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,but i'm already using html comment to identify the blocks. I just wanted to know if there's any feature available in django itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.

Additionally to what Bartek and Marius Grigaitis -- indeed your template logic should be as simple as possible, and django oh pure html comments should do what you need -- I would also explicit the importance of indentation in your template logic, which is for me the simplest, most correct and the clearest way to keep track of the beggining and end of my if/endif blocks.

Good Luck!